# Using an unsorted list (not sorted numerically) to search through a file

Tags: python, list, sorting

Here is a snippet of config.  Obviously there is more than this, but this is the important sections I'm dealing with.  I start by grabbing the customer bridge group assignment and then the corresponding interface to keep them "associated" with each other.  Then, I am trying to take the interface and grab the description and the dot1q tag from the top 8 lines using either the nested for loop or list comprehension, which neither are working.

```
interface Bundle-Ether30.43 l2transport description Customer4
interface Bundle-Ether30.43 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 43
interface Bundle-Ether30.692 l2transport description Customer2
interface Bundle-Ether30.692 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 692
interface Bundle-Ether30.839 l2transport description Customer3
interface Bundle-Ether30.839 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 839
interface Bundle-Ether30.1076 l2transport description Customer1
interface Bundle-Ether30.1076 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 1076
l2vpn bridge group customer1bg bridge-domain customer1bg interface Bundle-Ether30.1076
l2vpn bridge group customer2bg bridge-domain customer2bg interface Bundle-Ether30.692
l2vpn bridge group customer3bg bridge-domain customer3bg interface Bundle-Ether30.839
l2vpn bridge group customer4bg bridge-domain customer4bg interface Bundle-Ether30.43
```

Let's say I have a list of interfaces that are not sorted numerically:

```
Bundle-Ether30.1076
Bundle-Ether30.692
Bundle-Ether30.839
Bundle-Ether30.43
```

These interfaces exist within a configuration file that I have pulled down from a rancid repository into memory.  When I search for those interfaces within the config file, the output results are now sorted numerically (because that is how they show up in the config file) instead of staying in the order above.

I have tried a nested for loop:

```
interfacedescription = []
for line in config:
    for each in interfacelist:
        if each in line and 'description' in line:
            interfacedescription.append(line.split('description ')[-1])
```

I have also tried using list comprehension and get the same results:

```
interfacedescription = [x.split('description ')[-1] for x in config if any(y in x for y in config) and 'description' in x]

for interface, description in zip(interfacelist, interfacedescription):
    print(interface+'\t\t'+description)
```

Output looks something like this:

```
Bundle-Ether30.43          Bundle-Ether30.43 description
Bundle-Ether30.692         Bundle-Ether30.692 description
Bundle-Ether30.839         Bundle-Ether30.839 description
Bundle-Ether30.1076        Bundle-Ether30.1076 description
```

I want the output to look like this (which follows the initial sorting from the interface listing):

```
Bundle-Ether30.1076        Bundle-Ether30.1076 description
Bundle-Ether30.692         Bundle-Ether30.692 description
Bundle-Ether30.839         Bundle-Ether30.839 description
Bundle-Ether30.43          Bundle-Ether30.43 description
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `config` is here? Or a sample of the configuration file itself?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Based on what you've provided so far, it seems like the simplest answer is that the data is getting sorted, you just don't realize it. Also, it's not clear why you're searching for data from the config file in the same config file -- maybe there's a typo there or something. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for more tips.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly - just swap the two `for` loops.

Comment: BTW, I edited to fix the formatting. Check out [code formatting help](/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try what *jasonharper* suggested (see comments to your answer):

```
config = """\
interface Bundle-Ether30.43 l2transport description Customer4
interface Bundle-Ether30.43 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 43
interface Bundle-Ether30.692 l2transport description Customer2
interface Bundle-Ether30.692 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 692
interface Bundle-Ether30.839 l2transport description Customer3
interface Bundle-Ether30.839 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 839
interface Bundle-Ether30.1076 l2transport description Customer1
interface Bundle-Ether30.1076 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 1076
l2vpn bridge group customer1bg bridge-domain customer1bg interface Bundle-Ether30.1076
l2vpn bridge group customer2bg bridge-domain customer2bg interface Bundle-Ether30.692
l2vpn bridge group customer3bg bridge-domain customer3bg interface Bundle-Ether30.839
l2vpn bridge group customer4bg bridge-domain customer4bg interface Bundle-Ether30.43\
""".split("\n")

# Let's say I have a list of interfaces that are not sorted numerically:

interfacelist = """\
Bundle-Ether30.1076
Bundle-Ether30.692
Bundle-Ether30.839
Bundle-Ether30.43\
""".split("\n")

interfacedescription = []
for line in config:
    for each in interfacelist:
        if ((each in line) and ('description' in line)):
            interfacedescription.append(line.split('description ')[-1])

print(interfacedescription)

interfacedescription = []
for each in interfacelist:
    for line in config:
        if each in line and 'description' in line:
            interfacedescription.append(line.split('description ')[-1])
print(interfacedescription)
```

gives as output:

```
['Customer4', 'Customer2', 'Customer3', 'Customer1']
['Customer1', 'Customer2', 'Customer3', 'Customer4']
```

You can see that that second version of the code creates the output you want.

Comment: There is nothing in the interfacedescription list with this method.

Comment: It there is nothing with this method in that list, then ... there is nothing in this list using the code you provided in your question either, right?

Comment: In the code I provided, I DO get the descriptions to populate, but they are not in the same "order" as the initial interface list that is NOT numerically sorted.

Comment: If you run the code in my answer you should get the descriptions populated in the order they appear in the interface list. Hmmm ... Have you placed the code directly after your code version in the script file you run? No idea what could be reason that you experience an empty list as result.

Comment: I am just testing your code with your data. The results are not as you describe in your question ...

Comment: See my updated answer for evidence that my answer populates the list with results and changes their order according to your request.

Comment: Thank you Claudio.  I had moved the "config" and "interfacelist" lines around, but forgot to move the "for line" and "for each" statements along with them and that was why my list was coming back empty.  Your solution does in fact work.